# How do I calculate the number of possible cases of polynomial equation (combinations) in Mathematica?

Tags: combinatorics

if I have the equation 
$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=x_1x_3+x_2x_4+x_1x_2x_4+x_1x_2x_3x_4$$

- How many equations are possible if two variables ?

when $x_1=x$ and the other four are y

when $x_2=x$ and the other four are y

when $x_3=x$ and the other four are y

when $x_4=x$ and the other four are y

I want to calculate the number of equations in each case

An example is if we have two variables. How many equation number we produce during compensation.

I suggest using combinations $C^2_4$ ... Is this true?

Can a program of work to calculate the number of possible cases if two variables

- And if three variables ....3 variables: if one variable is x, another is y and the other two are z, the we have .... possible cases; if one variable is x, the other two are y, and the other z, then we have ....possible cases.
- And the generalization of more than three.

For example:
if I have

```
f[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_] := a d + b e + b c d - a b c d - a b d e - b c d e + a b c d e
```

2 variables: if one variable is x, and the other four are y, we have five polynomials;

```
f[x, y, y, y, y]

f[y, x, y, y, y]

f[y, y, x, y, y]

f[y, y, y, x, y]

f[y, y, y, y, x]
```

Account Functions. How many function is there because order of variables is necessary

if two variables are x and the other three are y, we have $C^2
_5$ = 10 polynomials.

```
f[x, x, y, y, y]

f[x,y , x, y, y]

f[x, y, y, x, y]

f[x, y, y, y, x]
```

. . . 
. . . . . . . 
. . .

```
 f[y, x, x, y, y]

f[y,x , y, x, y]

f[y, x, y, y, x]
```

.....................

```
f[y,y , x, x, y]

f[y, y, x, y, x]
```

.......................

```
f[y, y, y, x, x]
```

Is this possible?

thanks for the help.

Comment: "the other four" - but you only have four.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the note See the new update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you need and I suspect your example is a reduced version of your actual problem, but a "brute force" approach is easily viable with only four parameters.

```
f[a_, b_, c_, d_] := a c + b d + a b d + a b c d

f2[a : {_, _, _, _}] := f @@@ Permutations[a] // Union

f2[{x, y, y, y}] // Column
```

> ```
> x y + y^2 + x y^2 + x y^3
> x y + y^2 + y^3 + x y^3
> ```

```
f2[{x, y, z, z}] // Column
```

> ```
> x z + y z + x y z + x y z^2
> x y + x y z + z^2 + x y z^2
> x z + y z + x z^2 + x y z^2
> x y + z^2 + x z^2 + x y z^2
> x z + y z + y z^2 + x y z^2
> x y + z^2 + y z^2 + x y z^2
> ```

```
f2[{w, x, y, z}] // Length
```

> ```
> 12
> ```

Comment: I want to calculate the number of equations in each case

An example is if we have two variables. How many equation number we produce during compensation

Comment: @Emadkareem Please edit your question to include explicit examples of what you mean.

Comment: See the new update

Comment: @Emad I don't understand.  With your new example you seem to not want to eliminate equivalent polynomials (which is why I used `Union`) therefore I do not understand why the polynomial matters at all?  Your values five and ten are directly computed with `Multinomial[1, 4]` and `Multinomial[2, 3]` -- is that all you want?

Comment: See the new update ...In the first case of the example you will understand the idea

Comment: @Emad As I already said `Multinomial` computes this.  `Multinomial[2, 3]` evaluates to `10`, matching the length of `Permutations[{x, x, y, y, y}]`.